pg_upgrade failing { pg13.7 -> pg15.6} using pglogical method
I am trying to upgrade PostgreSQL (RHEL 7) from version 13.7 to 15.6 using pglogical.
My Standby(destination) machine has following rpms,
postgresql13-pglogical-3.7.16-1.el7.x86_64
postgresql15-pglogical-2.4.2-1.el7.x86_64

\-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 547560 May 16  2022 /usr/pgsql-13/lib/pglogical.so
\-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6976 May 16  2022 /usr/pgsql-13/lib/pglogical_output.so
\-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 251344 Oct 18  2022 /usr/pgsql-15/lib/pglogical.so
\-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6976 Oct 18  2022 /usr/pgsql-15/lib/pglogical_output.so

And Primary(Source) has ,
postgresql13-pglogical-3.7.16-1.el7.x86_64

\-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 547560 May 16  2022 /usr/pgsql-13/lib/pglogical.so
\-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6976 May 16  2022 /usr/pgsql-13/lib/pglogical_output.so

pg_upgrade check mode went fine , but it failed while running real mode.
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 13027; 1255 3375648004 FUNCTION alter_subscription_add_log("text", "text", boolean, "regclass", "text"[], "text"[]) postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  could not find function "pglogical_alter_subscription_add_log" in file "/usr/pgsql-15/lib/pglogical.so"
Command was: CREATE FUNCTION "pglogical"."alter_subscription_add_log"("sub_name" "text", "log_name" "text", "log_to_file" boolean DEFAULT true, "log_to_table" "regclass" DEFAULT NULL::"regclass", "conflict_type" "text"[] DEFAULT NULL::"text"[], "conflict_resolution" "text"[] DEFAULT NULL::"text"[]) RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE "c"
    AS '$libdir/pglogical', 'pglogical_alter_subscription_add_log';

-- For binary upgrade, handle extension membership the hard way
ALTER EXTENSION "pglogical" ADD FUNCTION "pglogical"."alter_subscription_add_log"("sub_name" "text", "log_name" "text", "log_to_file" boolean, "log_to_table" "regclass", "conflict_type" "text"[], "conflict_resolution" "text"[]);

Note: pglogical version at source : pglogical: 3.7.16
Am I missing any packages?
Any pointers much appreciated

The above error due to pglogical version mismatch.
